# What introductory textbook is available about the corticostriatal brain circuitry?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, brain, dopamine

I want to understand the basal ganglia better. In particular, I want to understand the role of the corticostriatal brain circuitry for non-motor functions, including emotion and cognition.
I have found some recent review papers that provide solid overviews e.g.

Haber, S. N. (2016). Corticostriatal circuitry. *Dialogues in Clinical Neuroscience*, 18(1), 7–21. PCMCID: [PMC4826773](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4826773/).

and

Shipp, S. (2017). The functional logic of corticostriatal connections. *Brain Structure and Function*, 222(2), 669-706. doi: [10.1007/s00429-016-1250-9](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00429-016-1250-9)

However, a more comprehensive textbook would be ideal - are there any introductory textbooks that cover the basal ganglia and the corticostriatal brain circuitry in detail?

Comment: I edited your question to be less confusing and for readability.  The confusing bit to me was that the title read that you was asking about the Basal Ganglia, yet the body of the question covered the whole corticostriatal brain circuitry.  Feel free to edit further if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Although my formal training involved an element of neuroscience, it was not heavy on neuroscience so I am not aware of any specific neuroscience textbooks.  However, another article you may be interested in is:

Mathai, A., & Smith, Y. (2011). The Corticostriatal and Corticosubthalamic Pathways: Two Entries, One Target. So What? *Frontiers in Systems Neuroscience, 5, 64*. doi: [10.3389/fnsys.2011.00064](http://doi.org/10.3389/fnsys.2011.00064) pcmcid: [PMC3149683](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3149683/)

Just like the two articles you linked to, this article is also open access, therefore, free to view or download as PDF without a paywall.

> **Abstract**
>
> The basal ganglia receive cortical inputs through two main stations – the striatum and the subthalamic nucleus (STN). The information flowing along the corticostriatal system is transmitted to the basal ganglia circuitry via the “direct and indirect” striatofugal pathways, while information that flows through the STN is transmitted along the so-called “hyperdirect” pathway. The functional significance of this dual entry system is not clear. Although the corticostriatal system has been thoroughly characterized anatomically and electrophysiologically, such is not the case for the corticosubthalamic system. In order to provide further insights into the intricacy of this complex anatomical organization, this review examines and compares the anatomical and functional organization of the corticostriatal and corticosubthalamic systems, and highlights some key issues that must be addressed to better understand the mechanisms by which these two neural systems may interact to regulate basal ganglia functions and dysfunctions.